# Merging pandas dataframes with unnamed columns

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if this is a duplicate, couldn't find an answer specific to what I'm asking.

I have `df`:

```
    Unnamed: 0         2018-11-15       2018-11-16
0    China                  1.00             72.25
1    Mexico                 5.00             60.07
2    USA                    6.00             31.30
```

And I have `df2`:

```
    Unnamed: 0         2018-11-17       
0    China                  6.00             
1    Mexico                 25.00            
2    USA                    2.00     
3    Canada                 0.00
```

I've tried merging them, but with no proper results. I'm trying to get an output that would resemble this:

```
     Unnamed: 0         2018-11-15       2018-11-16      2018-11-17  
0    China                  1.00             72.25             6.00 
1    Mexico                 5.00             60.07            25.00 
2    USA                    6.00             31.30             2.00  
3    Canada                  NaN               NaN             0.00
```

And then the next day `df2` could be:

```
    Unnamed: 0         2018-11-18       
0    China                  14.00             
1    Mexico                 3.00            
2    USA                    0.00     
3    Canada                 5.00
```

And once merged with the previous output, nets me something like:

```
     Unnamed: 0         2018-11-15       2018-11-16      2018-11-17   2018-11-18 
0    China                  1.00             72.25             6.00        14.00 
1    Mexico                 5.00             60.07            25.00         3.00
2    USA                    6.00             31.30             2.00         0.00 
3    Canada                  NaN               NaN             0.00         5.00
```

And so on, and so on. I think I'm having trouble because this is being merged with an updated data frame once a day. And because the column that contains country names to merge on is unnamed. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the code you tried to merge?

Comment: `df = pd.merge(df1, df2)` , that was my last attempt, but if you try to merge `df` with different data as in my last example of `df2`, it outputs gibberish. Example, `df3 = pd.merge(df2, df)`

Comment: Please read in your data frames using `pd.read_csv(..., index_col=[0])` to read in the first column as an index (instead of an unnamed column), then you'll be able to do `df3 = df1.join(df2)` (a merge on the index)

Comment: This has done it, thank you.